# Provided service not being used by descendent components

Tags: angular, angular5

#### The Setup

So I have several reusable components that I am attempting to use together. They are as follows:

- SmartNavTileGroup
- SmartNavTile
- RadioCheckboxGroup
- RadioCheckboxWrapper

When implementing in the markup, it looks like this:

```
<smart-nav-tile-group>
    <smart-nav-tile></smart-nav-tile>
    <smart-nav-tile></smart-nav-tile>
</smart-nav-tile-group>
```

The `SmartNavTileGroup` component implements `RadioCheckboxGroup` and the `SmartNavTile` component implements `RadioCheckboxWrapper`.

So in the resulting markup they go in this order:

```
<smart-nav-tile-group>
    <radio-checkbox-group>
        <smart-nav-tile>
            <radio-checkbox-wrapper>
```

#### The Goal

The goal here is to allow `RadioCheckboxGroup` to have access to all instances of `RadioCheckboxWrapper` within it.

#### What I've Tried

So far I've tried `ViewChildren` and `ContentChildren`, as well as `forwardRef` injection and using a shared service to accomplish this.

#### The Problem

So far the only thing that gets me close to getting this working is the service.

`RadioCheckboxGroupService` resides with and is provided by both `RadioCheckboxGroup` module and component.  This has the desired result of creating a service for each `RadioCheckboxGroup`.

However whenever this service is injected into `RadioCheckboxWrapper` a third instance of the service is created and all instances of `RadioCheckboxWrapper` are put into this instance of `RadioCheckboxGroupService` regardless of where they are on the page.

So for some reason they are creating their own global singleton instead of using the individual instances created by `RadioCheckBoxGroup` and for the life of me I can't figure out why they aren't using the service instance provided by `RadioCheckboxGroup.

As you can see from this series of console logs, each `RadioCheckboxGroup` creates an instance of the `RadioCheckboxGroupService` when expected, however each instance of `RadioCheckboxWrapper` is adding itself to a third global singleton instance of `RadioCheckboxGroupService` instead of the services set up by `RadioCheckboxGroup`:

[image]

#### The Question

How can I get each instance of `RadioCheckboxWrapper` to use the services created and provided by their ancestor instances of `RadioCheckboxGroup` instead of creating a global service and adding themselves to that?

Answer (score 0):

#### The Answer

The solution here was to ensure that `RadioCheckboxWrapper` was imported into the module where the `RadioCheckboxGroupService` was being provided.  In this case it needed to be imported into the `RadioCheckboxGroup` module.